# How to use simple modal jquery plugin to get a dialog of table?

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to show a popup when I click on a link which is basically done by jquery plugin simple modal.
In my **template.php file**,

```
function theme_name_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name') .'/js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js');

    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name') . '/js/theme_name.js');

}

function theme_name_process_views_view_field(&$vars) {
// $plus_icon is a variable defined inside this function. 
 $output = "<a id='abc-modal-$nid' class='abc-modal' href='#'>$plus_icon</a>";
 $output .= "<div id='abc-modal-content-$nid' class='abc-modal-content'></div>";
 $vars['view']->result[$key]->field_field_flag[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = $output;
}
```

And in the theme_name.js file

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.abc = {
('.abc-modal').click(function (e) {
                var key = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^abc-modal-(\d+)$/, "$1");
                $.post(Drupal.settings.basePath + 'queue-log', {nid : key},
                       function(data) {
                           if (data) {
                               $('#abc-modal-content-'+key).html(data.html);
                               $('#abc-modal-content-'+key).modal();
                           }
                       }, "json" );
                return false;
            });
```

.....
How can I get the simple modal jquery plugin working so that when I click on a link mentioned in $output variable() I get a popup displaying contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is snippet which can be helpful for you to add open the link in simple modal plugin

```
// Get the click action on link
$('.abc-modal').click(function() {

// Get href attribute.
  var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');

 /*  Three things here
 1. Append a div to the pop-up body
 2. Keep it hidden.      
 3. load the content on the link to the div(#content is the id from where you want to load the content to the pop-up) */

      $('<div id="any-id-you-want"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load(href+' #content', function(){
        }).modal({
        overlayClose: true, 
        autoResize: true, 
        minHeight: 600, 
        minWidth:800 , 
        opacity:80,
        overlayCss: {
          backgroundColor:"black"
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Make sure js files are loading.

Comment: why do we use appendTo('body') ? I have tried the above code but it takes me to the href link . Pls can u explain what should be written in place of '#content'

Comment: #content is just an id and you can replace it with any container wrapping around the content you want on pop-up

Comment: I have a code where href = "#" and then when I tried  $("#abc-modal-content").modal(); I got the popup .Then why is `{
        overlayClose: true, 
        autoResize: true, 
        minHeight: 600, 
        minWidth:800 , 
        opacity:80,
        overlayCss: {
          backgroundColor:"black"
        }
      }` this required in modal function ? Also I get the popup but the cross sign is missing Is the missing of cross sign related to above code you have implemented ?

Comment: ah, this is just inline css, to the popup,

Comment: Pls check the updated comment

Comment: @harshal please check http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ you will get the close option as well.
its just css you need to add to have your close option over there.

Comment: ok.actually i was going through the same link thnx for help